# template class overloading

Tags: c++, class, templates, overloading

I am wondering how to overload a template class. If I have the following class. I want to create different function for different type of T.

```
template <class T>
class A {
    T data;
public:
    void print_data(void);
}
```

if the T is double type, I need a function like following pseudo code:

```
template <class T>
void A<double>::print_data(){
   printf("%g",date);
}
```

if the T is complex type, I need it work like this:

```
template <class T>
void A< complex<double> >::print_data(){
    printf("%g+%gi",data.real(),date.imag());
}
```

How should I achieve this goal. Thank you!

I find a solution but I think it is not very good. The basic idea is using a input parameter for overloading.

```
template <class T>
class A {
public:
    T data;
    void print_data(double);
    void print_data(complex<T>);       
}

template <class T>
void A<T>::print_data(double){
   printf("%g",date);
}
template <class T>
void A<T>::print_data(complex<T>){
    printf("%g+%gi",data.real(),date.imag());
}

int main(void) 
{
    //just demonstrate the idea, may not work
    A<double>    ddata;
    A<complex>   cdata;
    ddata.data = 2.0;
    cdata.data = complex(1,2);

    ddata->print_data(ddata);
    cdata->print_data(cdata);
    return 0;
}
```

anyone have better solution?

Comment: Have you tried to? (don't forget the function return type!)

Comment: To Skippy, I want to create the print_data() function. what I giving here is wrong, they are just showing what I want to get.

Comment: To David: Yes, I have tried the above code with return type,I get an compile error.

Answer (score 1):

Just specialize your template functions for concrete types:

```
template <>
void A<double>::print_data()
{
    std::cout << data << std::endl;
}
template<>
void A<complex<double> >::print_data(){
    std::cout <<  data.real() << "+" << data.imag() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: This solution forces you to redefine everything that is common in each one of the specializations of the template.